# Can't make a square canvas inside a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

All I want is to make the canvas inside in the dialog a perfect square. For some reason it keeps rendering taller than wide.

Following is a minimal version of my code that duplicates the problem. At least in Firefox and Chrome.

```
$(function() {
  var docwidth = $(document).outerWidth();
  var modalwidth = (docwidth > 767) ? 750 : 450;

  // #pscanvas is the div that wraps the canvas
  $("#pscanvas").width(modalwidth / 10 * 9).height(modalwidth / 10 * 9);

  // #psc is the canvas itself
  $("#psc").width(modalwidth / 10 * 9).height(modalwidth / 10 * 9);

  // #psc-dialog is the dialog div
  $("#psc-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: modalwidth
  });
  $("#psc-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Here is a ---> [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ncafwhff/4/show/)

How can I can make the canvas (with the black border) a square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `jQuery.width()` and `jQuery.height()` methods, use `width` and `height` properties of `HTMLElement` as `Canvas` elements does not consider `CSS` properties.

```js
$(function() {
  var docwidth = $(document).outerWidth();
  var modalwidth = (docwidth > 767) ? 750 : 450;
  $("#psc-dialog").width(modalwidth).height(modalwidth + 25);
  $("#pscanvas").width(modalwidth / 10 * 9).height(modalwidth / 10 * 9);
  $("#psc").get(0).width = (modalwidth / 10 * 9);
  $("#psc").get(0).height = (modalwidth / 10 * 9);
  $("#psc-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  $("#psc-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ku15uu7y/)

Comment: My experience and understanding is that the height and width attributes determine the size of the canvas itself, while it may still be scaled with css. I've used this to create a magnifying glass tool for a canvas based app before. I'll need to be able to use both the canvas properties as well as the css properties in this app, and while using the canvas properties alone as in your example does make it a square, when used in addition to the css properties, it becomes oblong again. Any ideas? http://fiddle.jshell.net/ncafwhff/6/

Comment: @RobertParham – As per the provided fiddle, width as well as height of the canvas is `502`, isn't it square ?

Comment: It looks like it in the fiddle, but I think it's just taking up 100% of the height. It's more apparent in the full screen version: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ncafwhff/6/show/

Comment: @RobertParham – If it was talking 100%, changing the height by opening `Developers tools` would have changed it, inspect the element and test...

Comment: I think the issue may only present when the viewport is > 767px. It's a square on my project when I shrink the window as well.

Comment: I'm not really looking for responsiveness right now. I don't expect the user will resize the app while this modal is open. I just want the canvas to be a square when opened on a full screen and while scaling the canvas with css.

Comment: @RobertParham – That is how it is right now.... Do share the scenario when it fails...

Comment: I shared it a few comments up, look at the fullscreen version I posted. This is a screenshot of how it renders, clearly taller than wide: http://i.imgur.com/FilK23R.png

Comment: I literally checked it using scale... There is no difference... Just make sure you do not use `css` as well as `Element` width and Height properties..  For your reference... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ku15uu7y/1/

Comment: Thank you for your patience. You're absolutely correct my screen is just so short the scrolling made it look oblong. When I physically measured it I realized it really is square.

Comment: @RobertParham – No problem mate! It is human tendency ;) I am glad it helped!